# Popup script positioning the popup module too high

Tags: jquery, popup

I am using this code approach http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html for the popup forms on this page http://imagespace.businesscatalyst.com/canon-dr-systems.html  Hitting the Enquire link activates the popup module. My problem is that the popup box is placed at the top of the page by the script, it is adding style="top: 204.5px;" to the main div, and this places it off the screen. Ideally I want it to popup in the same position as the item activating it. I am not at all sure on how to change the following to affect this, any help on it greatly appreciated.

(I have temporarily added a class with a margin-top of 600px which is pushing the module down to where it needs to be, but this isn't an ideal fix.)

```
<script>
        $(function() {

            var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'>   </div>");

            $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("body").append(appendthis);
                $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
                //$(".js-modalbox").fadeIn(500);
                var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
                $('#' + modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());
            });


            $(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
                $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
                    $(".modal-overlay").remove();
                });

            });

            $(window).resize(function() {
                $(".modal-box").css({
                    top: ($(window).height() - $(".modal-box").outerHeight()) / 2,
                    left: ($(window).width() - $(".modal-box").outerWidth()) / 2
                });
            });

            $(window).resize();

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your [website](http://imagespace.businesscatalyst.com/canon-dr-systems.html#). And Suggesting below CSS to apply.
ie, Make the modal popup `position:fixed;` . It will help you to popup at the same place.

```
.modal-box {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Also remove the window resize function from your js.

```
   /* $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".modal-box").css({
            top: ($(window).height() - $(".modal-box").outerHeight()) / 2,
            left: ($(window).width() - $(".modal-box").outerWidth()) / 2
        });
    });*/
```

Comment: Hey thank you! That helped a lot. I really appreciate it.